# DeflaterOutputStream compression on Mainframe/Windows

Tags: zip, jms, compression, mq

I am attempting to send a compressed JMS message to MQ.
The JMS body is compressed along with business specific Header (key<->value pairs).

The compression is done on Windows 64 bit machine.
IBM MQ and the consumer are running in a Mainframe machine.

I am seeing exceptions thrown when the JMS is decompressed at Mainframe (by consumer).

```
Exception      - java.util.zip.ZipException
                - java.util.zip.ZipException: unknown compression method
```

We use java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream for the compression/decompression.
and we set the encosing to UTF8 during compression

I am trying to understand - if this is a platform related issue?
Since When testing the compression/decompression in windows - there is no exception.
Also there is no exception thrown when the compression is done in 64 bit Solaris and decompressed at Mainframe.
Problem seems to occur only when compression is done at Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the 3 different JREs (Windows, Solaris & mainframe) that you are using - maybe the Windows JRE, by default, is using a newer compress method.  Hence, you may need to force it to use a compression method that is supported by the mainframe JRE.  Also, are you using an Oracle or IBM JRE on Windows?  I would strongly suggest that you use an IBM JRE on Windows.  Time to RTM.

Comment: Looks like the 64 bit Solaris & Mainframe uses Oracle Java 6. Windows is on Java 7. Not sure if this is the root cause. We are now downgrading Java to 6 in the Windows machine. This also means the MQ libraries we are currently using needs downgrading. once done I will again test this by publishing to MQ.